# Set equal limits for y-axis for two figures

Tags: matlab, plot, axes

How can I make the vertical axes of two plots equal?

For example:

```
a = [1 2 3; 21 1 3; 4 2 3; 4 5 6]
```

After plotting `plot(a(1, :))` I get the following figure:
[image]

I have done some simple operations:

```
[U E V] = svd(a);
figure(2);
plot(U(1,:))
```

And get another figure:
[image]

How do I make the y-axis limits of both plots equal? Is it with the `axes equal` command?

**UPDATE:**
I've used the following commands:

```
figure (1)
ylim([0 3])
plot(a(1,:))
figure (2);
ylim([0 3])
plot(U(1,:))
```

But get the same result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ylim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ylim.html) to force limits on the y-axis. For example:

```
figure(1)
%// Some plotting...
ylim([0 3])

figure(2)
%// Some more plotting
ylim([0 3])
```

This ensures that the y-axis is limited to the range [0, 3] in both plots. You can do the same for the limits of the x-axis with the command [`xlim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlim.html).

Also note that if you want to set the limits for both axes at once, instead of using `xlim` and `ylim` (two commands), you can use [`axis`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html) (one command).

Comment: does this make y  axes equal?

Comment: to each other at different figure,for example in my case y axes scales are different from each other,can i make them equal to each other?

Comment: @dato MATLAB sets the limits for the y-axis automatically. `ylim` manually enforces the limits to the values you decide. If you want to make sure that the limits are the same use `ylim` with the same values for both plots.

Comment: i have tested but they are different i will upload it now

Comment: @dato Compare this to my example. You have to put `ylim` _after_ the plotting operation.

Comment: if i want to set limit for x axes,use same procedure yes?or if i want both together

Comment: @data You can use `xlim` like you use `ylim`. Note that if you're forcing manual limits for both axes, you can use `axis` instead of `xlim` and `ylim`, it is shorter (one command instead of two).

Comment: for example to force  both axes limit three it should be like this?axes[0 3 0 3]?

Comment: @dato Basically yes, but the command is "axis", not "axes", and you forgot parentheses. The correct command should be `axis([0 3 0 3])`.

Comment: aaa yes axes  means different one as i know :D

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `ylim` or `xlim` functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can clone the limits of one plot to another plot in this fashion:

```
h1 = figure;
% do first plot...

h2 = figure;
%do second plot...

% set first figure as active
figure(h1); 

%get limits properties of the axes that are drawn in Figure 1
xL = get(gca, 'XLim');
yL = get(gca, 'YLim');

%switch to second figure and set it as active
figure(h2);

%set axis limit properties of Figure 2 to be the same as in Figure 1
set(gca, 'XLim', xL);
set(gca, 'YLim', yL);
```